# Why does my project stop launching on an actual device (iPhone)?

Tags: ios, xcode

First off, I don't have a developer account or anything with Apple. When I put my project on an iPhone for testing purposes everything works just fine without any runtime errors. However, After sometime (maybe after 4 hours or sometimes 2 days) the project just stops launching. I tap on the icon and a white screen comes up and then it just quits. What might be the source of the problem?

P.S I apologize in advance for not posting any code with this question, frankly I don't know which part of my code to include for this situation.

Edit: This is the performance when I run the App in Xcode. Is taking up that amount of memory normal? Because I think it's insanely high.

[image]

Comment: Maybe its because of memory overloading the app goes to suspended state. Please check the Debug Navigator in Xcode while running the app from Xcode.

Comment: Have you looked at some of the doocumentation about crashes from Apple? E.g. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1747/_index.html or https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: I flagged this question, because in my opinion this question is too broad.

Comment: @A.Jam : Have you tried to launch the app after clearing it from recent menu in iPhone?

Comment: @manuzi1 Thank you for your contribution. How would you suggest asking this question for it not to be too broad? Any suggestions would help.

Comment: @Poles I did what you suggested and update my question with a picture; please take a look.

Comment: @A.Jam : Which iPhone is this? I think you should keep the app open for 4 hours or 2 days as you said and check the memory bar in Xcode.

Comment: @Poles I am using a 6S. Keep the app open for four hours in Xcode you mean?

Comment: @A.Jam : I mean you should keep the app running for 4 hours or more. Besides, according to your latest update it seems like its a memory management issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129248/discussion-between-a-jam-and-poles).

Comment: @A.Jam Try to give more details. Which iOS, emulator, real phone, etc. Where did you run it, What did you try? Do you have any logs and so on.

Comment: I am using the iPhone 6S the latest version of Xcode and swift and iOS... latest versions of everything apart from the iPhone. @manuzi

Answer (score 0):

For testing your app in real device you are using apple ID as team in xcode.

So for that team the provisioning profile are only valid for 7 days max. So if your certificates are expires than it will crash after click on icon.

Solution is that go to xcode preference -> account -> select your account -> click on view details and from list download your profile. and run again.

If still app is not running than you have to change bundle identifier in general settings.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To find out why your app is exiting on launch, you need to look at the console logs.

To do that:

1. Window -> Devices
2. Select your device on the left under DEVICES.  Make sure your device is plugged in via USB cable.
3. Click on the little icon that looks like an up chevron inside of a box at the bottom.  See screen shot.
4. Run your app, see logs.  There will be error messages.  Search Google / StackOverflow for those errors.

It's probably a certificate thing, as mentioned elsewhere.

[image: Click the box with up arrow]